# Binary File issues

Tags: c++, file-io, binaryfiles

Hey guys i'm working on this simple bank account program with binary files.
For some odd reason, i can't read from the file. Or to be more on point the program crashes whenever i try to read from the file.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include "Account_Querry.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Account_Querry Account;

    int choice;
    cout<<"***Acount Information System***"<<endl;
    while(true)
    {
        cout<<"Select one option below ";
        cout<<"\n\t1-->Add record to file";
        cout<<"\n\t2-->Show All records in file";
        cout<<"\n\t3-->Search Record from file";
        cout<<"\n\t4-->Update Record";
        cout<<"\n\t5-->Delete Record";
        cout<<"\n\t6-->Quit";
        cout<<"\nEnter your choice: ";
        cin>>choice;
        switch(choice)
        {
        case 1:
            Account.write_rec();
            break;
        case 2:
            //Account.search_rec();
            break;
        case 3:
            Account.read_rec();
            break;
        case 4:
            //Account.edit_rec();
            break;
        case 5:
           // Account.delete_rec();
            break;
        case 6:
            exit(0);
            break;
        default:
            cout<<"\nEnter corret choice" << endl;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Account_Querry.h

```
#ifndef ACCOUNT_QUERRY_H
#define ACCOUNT_QUERRY_H

#include <string>
#include <fstream>

class Account_Querry
{
private:
    int accountNo;
    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;
    double balance;
public:
    void setAccountNo(int accountNo);
    int getAccountNo();
    void setFirstName(std::string firstName);
    std::string getFirstName();
    void setLastName(std::string lastName);
    std::string getLastName();
    void setBalance(double balance);
    double getBalance();
    void read_data();
    void show_data();
    void write_rec();
    void read_rec();
    void search_rec();
    void edit_rec();
    void delete_rec();
};

#endif // ACCOUNT_QUERRY_H
```

Account_Querry.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
#include "Account_Querry.h"

using namespace std;

void Account_Querry::setAccountNo(int accountNo)
{
    this->accountNo = accountNo;
}

int Account_Querry::getAccountNo()
{
    return accountNo;
}

void Account_Querry::setFirstName(string firstName)
{
    this->firstName = firstName;
}

string Account_Querry::getFirstName()
{
    return firstName;
}

void Account_Querry::setLastName(string lastName)
{
    this->lastName = lastName;
}

string Account_Querry::getLastName()
{
    return lastName;
}

void Account_Querry::setBalance(double balance)
{
    this->balance = balance;
}

double Account_Querry::getBalance()
{
    return balance;
}

void Account_Querry::show_data()
{
    cout << "Current Information:" << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Name: " << firstName << ' ' << lastName << endl;
    cout << "Balance: " <<  balance << endl;
    cout << "ID#: " << accountNo << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << endl;
}

void Account_Querry::read_data()
{
    cout<<"\nEnter Account Number: ";
    cin>>accountNo;
    cin.ignore();

    cout<<"Enter First Name: ";
    getline(cin,firstName,'\n');

    cout<<"Enter Last Name: ";
    getline(cin,lastName,'\n');

    cout<<"Enter Balance: ";
    cin>>balance;
}

void Account_Querry::write_rec()
{
    ofstream outfile("record.bank", ofstream::app);
    read_data();
    outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(this), sizeof(*this));
    outfile.close();
    system("cls");
}

void Account_Querry::read_rec()
{
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("record.bank", ios::binary);
    if(!infile)
    {
        cout<<"Error in Opening! File Not Found!!"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    cout<<"\n****Data from file****"<<endl;
    while(!infile.eof())
    {
        if(infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(this), sizeof(*this))>0)
        {
            show_data();
        }
    }
    infile.close();
}
```

Comment: ANy error messages? If so, which line?

Comment: File-not-found isn't the only reason an `ifstream` may fail to open, just fyi. And blasting over `this` with a file read where `this` has non-POD members is a recipe for disaster. Looking back I see you *wrote* it the same way, which is also wrong.

Comment: Since there's no magic in C++, `sizeof(*this)` bytes is not enough to contain a name like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfe+585,_Senior). So your method of reading and writing `Account_Querry` objects (which should be really spelled `Account_Query`) is inadequate. In fact this method cannot be used to read and write anything that contains pointers or virtual functions or just about anything remotely non-trivial (and `std::string` is non-trivial). You need [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) which is not expressible as simple `istream::read` or `ostream::write`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, thanks for posting the whole code.

I just created an empty Visual Studio project in Windows and created the 3 files and copied the code you had posted in your question.

The code seems to execute perfectly fine, although while executing, the `Option 2` doesn't show all the records in the file. `Option 3` does show all the records in the file. You could update the Options section for that.

Apart from that, I compiled to create 32 bit binaries and 64 bit binaries and both of them seemed to work fine. `Option 1` is adding new records and `Option 3` is printing all the records. If I try to execute `Option 3`(show all records) before adding even a single record (delete the bank.record file), it is printing error message as well.

Can you tell how you are compiling the code **(VisualStudio/gcc/..)** on which OS (Windows/Ubuntu/..)?

Also what inputs are you giving while executing. Are you entering any non-ASCII character names like some Japanese characters?

One suggestion is: **Not to dump a class object into a binary file** (as done in `write_rec`). **Better create a structure with fixed size variables** (not using any string/vector).

For example, instead of string use character array, also instead of vector use static array etc. This will avoid a lot of read back issues.

Hope this helps to resolve your issue.